# How to show schema in json paramater in multipart/form-data in Swagger UI?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm using OpenApi 3.0 and Swagger UI.

(Swashbuckle and ASP.Net Core if it's important)

I have `multipart/form-data` which has 2 parameter:

- `ProductToAdd` object description in JSON
- `Image` as file.

I have schemas and examples defined.

For now I managed to do this
[image: My result]

And I'm targeting something like this:

[image: Target result]

My question is how to render schemas and examples like in the second pictures?
I didn't find anything helpful in swagger.json and so.

Ps. Execute work perfectly if you are curious.

@edit

I've made nuget package for that. You can find it [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.JsonMultipartFormDataSupport)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently (as of August 2023) Swagger UI does not display the schemas of object-type fields in `multipart/*` requests, it only displays the example values for these fields. Here's the corresponding feature request:

[Display static documentation information for multipart properties in OpenAPI 3.0 files](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5169)

Comment: Ohh... that's sad